# STACKING OF TABS similar to iPad Chrome app

Tags: ios, tabbar

I need to develop tab bar similar to Chrome's tab bar functionality on iPad. If the user opens more then 5 tabs it displays the extra tabs as a stack:

[stacked tabs http://uploads.hipchat.com/26718/169836/yfzwdgq80m4rzbw/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-10%20at%202.36.56%20PM.png](http://uploads.hipchat.com/26718/169836/yfzwdgq80m4rzbw/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-10%20at%202.36.56%20PM.png)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like that built into iOS, so you're going to have to implement it yourself. I'd suggest implementing the tab bar portion of the window as a separate view that knows how to draw the individual tabs, including the currently selected tab, and which sends an appropriate message to it's target or delegate object when one of the tabs is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a `UINavigationController` like Controller, with its own stack. If you are targeting iOS 5.0 and above you can use childViewController. The controller will have a tab bar, and container view. You will add view controllers to the stack of the Controller. From the stack you can form the tab bar item View, using titles of respective vc and views can overlap.

When they are selected bring the tab bar item view to the front and add the respective viewController as childViewController to the CustomTabBarController.